# How to set the JMenuItem's PopupLocation

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpopupmenu

As the title says, I need to manually set the popup location of the `JMenuItem`.

> jMenuItem1.getPopupLocation(null).setLocation(null);

I tried the above, but I can't proceed because it gives me compile errors. I think it is with the "null" values. Please give me an answer with an example.

I need to change the x coordinate ,because my "look and feel" is changing the x coordinate.

IS there any help.

Comment: JPopup has BoxLayout in API ........

Comment: Method getPopupLocation of JMenuItem will always return null

Comment: So is there any way to set the popup location of a JMenuItem
I need only the x coordinate to be change.

Comment: @Sniper you can only change the coordinate of the popup menu. Or you have asked about layouting of menu?

Comment: yes the coordinate.because my look and feel is changing it's x coordinate to a slight left...I'm using Synthatica Alu Oxide.